# Ensure that only a certain string can be used in the constructor

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

I have a class as follows:

```
class QueueItem {
  final String name;
  final Type type;
  final String imageUrl;


  const QueueItem({
    @required this.name,
    @required this.type,
    @required this.imageUrl,
  
  });
}
```

Where Type is an enum. This does not work, so I would like an alternative which ensures that only certain strings can be chosen.

Comment: What was the problem with the enum? (Just so I know what problem an alternative solution should take into account).

Comment: When I do QueueItem(type.Christmas) it gives an error. I guess that's because I'm inserting a string really, not an enum.

Comment: Can you try make an example showing your problem? I think it makes it easier to come with the best solution for you.

Comment: I would want to only insert "Christmas" or "New Years", not just any string. That's the issue.

Comment: How are the class going to be used? Is objects created based on some generated input so exceptions must be runtime? Or do you look for a statically checked solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question are complicated since you don't state how you are going to use the class and what kind of check you want. For example, if you just want some runtime checking you can do:

```
class QueueItem {
  final String name;
  final String type;
  final String imageUrl;
  
  QueueItem({
    @required this.name,
    @required this.type,
    @required this.imageUrl,
  }) {
    if (!['Christmas', 'New Years'].contains(type)) {
      throw Exception('$type is not a valid input!');
    }
  }
}
```

This solution will work but does not have any statically guarantees so it can be difficult to use it in code since it is not any statically checks for which value is valid for `type`.

If `type` is restricted to a subset of values I think the best is to use a `enum`. You are saying that is not going to work but here is an example:

```
enum Type { christmas, newYears }

class QueueItem {
  final String name;
  final String type;
  final String imageUrl;
  
  factory QueueItem({
    @required String name,
    @required Type type,
    @required String imageUrl,
  }) {
    switch (type) {
      case Type.christmas :
        return QueueItem._(name, 'Christmas', imageUrl);
      case Type.newYears :
        return QueueItem._(name, 'New Years', imageUrl);
      default :
        throw Exception('Unhandled enum value: $type');
    }
  }

  QueueItem._(this.name, this.type, this.imageUrl);
}
```

This solution makes it more clear what intended value you want to use as argument. The signature of the factory constructor restricts the valid values but the value itself in the class are now a `String`.

I have also made a more advance solution based on same principle which outsource the logic into another class:

```
class ValidStringValue {
  final String value;

  const ValidStringValue._(this.value);

  static ValidStringValue christmas = const ValidStringValue._('Christmas');
  static ValidStringValue newYears = const ValidStringValue._('New Years');
  static List<ValidStringValue> values = [christmas, newYears];

  factory ValidStringValue.fromString(String input) =>
      values.firstWhere((element) => element.value == input);
}

class QueueItem {
  final String name;
  final String type;
  final String imageUrl;

  QueueItem({
    @required this.name,
    @required ValidStringValue inputType,
    @required this.imageUrl,
  }) : type = inputType.value;
}
```

This solution does both have a statically way to assign a valid value and have `ValidStringValue.fromString` to create a value from a given input (which will crash if the input is not one of the accepted values).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm sorry for not giving you an explanation satisfactory enough. You nailed it anyway!